# On Macbook Pro, Can I dual OS X, with a windows 7 VHD, with option to open Win7 VHD with as VM once inside OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, vhd

So Im a Network tech, working mostly in a windows environment. We do some work with OS X/IOS devices, plus all the interconnectability between IOS and OS X devices convinced me to pickup a new MacBook Pro.

Im relatively new to OS X, having grown up with a DBA father, everything was PCs. 
Since I will be doing a lot of network diagnosis, and am worried about strictly running a Windows VM inside OS X. Im hesitant to add another layer of possible conflicts between Windows and whatever networking Im working on.

Would it be possible to have a dual boot setup where I can start up the machine in either OS X, or a Windows (possible bootable VHD?), but with the option once inside OS X, to load the Win7 VHD into Parallels as a VM?

I would prefer to do the majority of my day-to-day in OS X, accesing the VM if needed, but then boot into the VHD directly if I need to do serious network diagnosis.
Does this even make sense? Is it possible? Is it a last of time/resources? Are there any Windows network techs that do everything through OS X without issues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply - it is possible to have a Bootcamp Windows install which can also be used in ParallelsVM from inside the Mac -  so long as it is shut down each time before swapping.

Full setup info here - http://kb.parallels.com/en/112941

*Highlights:*

A Virtual Machine is created that uses the already existing Boot Camp partition of your Mac. Changes you make in Windows programs either while working in Mac OS X or when you start up your Mac in Windows using Boot Camp will be reflected in both places.

Windows running from Boot Camp has the following limitations:
It can't be paused
It can't be saved as a snapshot
It can't run in Safe Mode
It can't be compressed

Alternatively, you can create a new VM from an existing Bootcamp partition; afterwards they will be separate installations

Comment: "...so long as it is shut down each time before swapping."
You mean if Im currently in OS X, with the Bootcamp Windows running as in Parallels, I have to remember to shut down the Bootcamp "VM" before I attempt to restart the MBP in Windows?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it breaks things. I haven't done it in a while, but I have a feeling, judging by the wording on the site, it will simply not let you Suspend it in recent versions. Let me check & I'll add more info...

Comment: I wish I could give you a cookie! =)

Comment: Preparing to configure… upgrading boot camp… installing parallels tools… Reticulating Splines… this is taking a while… ;-) All cookies gratefully received, btw ;-)

Comment: OK - it does look like it will let you suspend, so you'd just have to remember not to, I guess. iirc, it would make the machine think it hadn't been shut down properly if you swap from VM to Bootcamp. I don't recall it really breaking anything badly, but it's been a while since I last used it that way.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. I pray your cookie stash runneth over.

Comment: One caveat, I feel I ought to mention, as I'm updating & tweaking the one I just ported over - ***boy***, it's slow running the BootcampVM, compared to just a standard VM version or, of course, the actual Bootcamp as boot.